# Do global extrema of functions also happen on critical points?

Tags: optimization, terminology

Do global extrema of functions also happen on critical points? The wikipedia page says the theorem holds for all local extrema. But does it hold for globals too? Or are globals also considered locals in this context as well (Im wondering because if it is so, why didnt they just say extrema, instead)

Comment: Global extrema are not "considered to be" local extrema, they _are_ local extrema! Look at the _definitions_ of the two terms. (Presumably the article says "local extrema" because a reader might misinterpret "extrema" to mean "global extrema", while it's clear that "local extrema" includes global extrema...)

Comment: A global extremum of a function with domain $[a,b]$ might occur at an endpoint, even though that endpoint is not a critical point.

Comment: @coffeemath I presume the endpoints are not critical points because they could still have non-zero derivatives due to the function being larger than the interval?

Comment: @Alan Take the case of $f(x)=x^2$ on $[0,1]$ whose maximum is $1$ at $x=1,$ but $f'(1)=2$ so that's not a critical point. The nonzero derivative at an endpoint is technically a "one sided" derivative, and if nonzero it may be the endpoint is a max or min (unless some other point in the interval has greater/lesser $f$ value).

Comment: A (local) extremum in the **interior** of the domain of a differentiable function is a critical point.

Comment: @user251257 thanks that really cleared it up for me.

Comment: @Alan in fact it is already sufficient, that the function is differentiable at the extremum.

Comment: @user251257 I am really interested in this but feel that basic calculus 1, 3 neglect many "edge" scenarios and do not rigorously cover optimization. Are there any introductory textbooks, threads, posts that you would recommend?

Comment: @Alan if you are really into optimization, you could try [Nocedal & Wright](http://users.iems.northwestern.edu/~nocedal/book/num-opt.html).

Comment: Well, in implicit functions(curves), you need to consider singular points on a curve as well for global extrema, if it has any.